# openmpi runtime error: Hello World run on hosts

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, openmpi

I'm trying to setup a cluster. Up to now I'm testing it only with 1 master and 1 slave. Running the script from the master it starts printing the HelloWorld, but then I get the following error:

```
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
```

it keeps printing HelloWorld and after a while:

```
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was: 
Process name: [[62648,1],2]
Exit code:    2
```

Then the code stops. By chance I tried to run the script from the slave and it works. I can't figure out why.
I've set passwordless SSH and running a file located in a nfs-mounted folder.
Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: please post your code !

Comment: It is a simple HelloWorld in Python:
`while True:
    print('HelloWorld')`

Then I do: `mpirun -np 4 -hostfile myhosts python3 helloworld.py`
Running it from the slave, the mpirun works perfectly. I'm trying to figure out why the master isn't able to do the same.

Comment: can you simply `python3 helloworld.py` on all your nodes ?

Comment: In serial and in local parallel it works on all nodes. The error arises when I try to use both master and slave from master, while from slave I can run the command and all runs.

Comment: this program basically overflows `stdout`, so I am not sure of what you expect. what if you `mpirun ... hostname` ? if it works, then I suggest you try a `mpi4py` helloworld.

Comment: It gives the same error. I'm running this simple script just to see if the nodes are properly connected. Running it from slave, I get what I expect (2 processes created on master, 2 on slave and the HelloWorld keeps on being printed). Running the same command from master, it stops after some seconds giving those errors I've written before.

Comment: try to `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include a.b.c.d/n --mca btl_tcp_if_include a.b.c.d/n ...` where `a.b.c.d/n` is the subnet of the network connecting master and slaves (for example `192.168.0.0/24`)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've run the command, but it works only on one node.

Comment: Did you set the right subnet ? Btw, is there any firewall on the front-end node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I've parsed all configurations files I've modified and finally there was a mistake in /etc/hosts. This is about the program working if launched from the node to the master and not viceversa. Regarding the program stopping, it is somehow related to the node not able to find the file to run. Fixed this setting up again the nfs.
Thanks for your help, hope this can be useful to other users.